# Select json tokens by a given value

Tags: c#, json, json.net

The following is the part of json that I receive from server:

```
[
{
    "outcome_id": "4",
    "items": [
        {
            "outcome_item_id": "4",
            "outcome_sport_id": "311"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "outcome_id": "4",
    "items": [
        {
            "outcome_item_id": "4",
            "outcome_sport_id": "312"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "outcome_id": "5",
    "items": [
        {
            "outcome_item_id": "4",
            "outcome_sport_id": "313"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I am using `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` and would like to know if there is a way to select all tokens with `outcome_id = 4`? I hope my questions is clear enough. Because I couldn't find any suitable solutions that satisfy my needs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create model classes as known types and deserialize the json. Then simply apply `Where` clause and `Select` using `Linq`;

```
public class Item
{
    public string outcome_item_id { get; set; }
    public string outcome_sport_id { get; set; }
}

public class JsonObject
{
    public string outcome_id { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonObject>>(json);
var outcome_ids = data.Where(x => x.outcome_id == "4").Select(x => x.outcome_id);
```

Comment: `Linq` was very convenient for me, but if this is the only way to solve the problem, then I go with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best method is to use class as @Stormcloak says..

this can only be an alternative..

```
JArray jarray = JArray.Parse(jsonString);
var outComeTokens = (from token in jarray
                                 where token["outcome_id"].Value<string>().Equals("4")
                                 select token).FirstOrDefault();
var first_outcome_sport_id = outComeTokens["items"].Value<JArray>()[0]["outcome_sport_id"].Value<string>();
```

//first_outcome_sport_id 312